# How to use Jekyll's pagination tool to sort through a subdirectory within _posts

Tags: for-loop, pagination, jekyll, liquid

Having trouble getting pagination to work properly in Jekyll using liquid markdown.

Used the paginator function and the posts do paginate but I'm trying to figure out a way to filter out what paginates.

Within my _posts directory I have a blog sub directory and a news subdirectory. I'm trying to only paginate the articles in blog and not news.

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where: 'category','Blog' %}
<ul class="list-unstyled blog-list">

  <!-- This loops through the paginated posts -->
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
    {% assign posts = site.posts | where: 'category','Blog' %}
    {% if post.category == 'Blog' %}

Do Stuff

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <!-- Pagination links -->
  <div class="pagination">
    {% if paginator.previous_page == 1 %}
      <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.previous_page > 1%}
      <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="page_number ">Page: {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>

    {% if paginator.next_page   %}
      <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next">Next</a>

    {% endif %}
  </div>
</ul>
```

I was trying to retrieve posts that have the category 'Blog' but when I run it, it paginates to the 7 articles per page I wanted, but some pages have less then 7 articles or no articles show up at all.

I think somethings wrong with my loop logic but I'm not sure what.

Maybe it's grabbing all the articles in _posts regardless but not showing the news articles on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jekyll Paginate does not have filtering features therefore it's not possible to filter paginated posts by category. I'd recommend You to look into [Octopress Paginate](https://github.com/octopress/paginate) plug-in which provides the feature.